# Trying to set a variable based on two user inputs in Swift

Tags: variables, swift, input

I am trying to replicate the Index Match function in excel. I have userInputQty and userInputLoc1. I need to use these to look at a chart and set a variable. 
For example:

```
if userInputLoc1 <= 1 && userInputQty <= 23 {
    let printCost6 = 2.50
} else { 
    let printCost6 = 5
}
```

I know that I can not access printCost6 outside of the if statement. That is my problem. I do not know how else to achieve the same thing. I have 7 different scenarios that I need the userInputs to be matched against. IE multiple qtys to multiple locations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var printCost6:Double = 0

let userInputLoc1 = 1
let userInputQty = 5

if userInputLoc1 <= 1 && userInputQty <= 23 {
    printCost6 = 2.50
} else {
    printCost6 = 5
}

// saving your Double data to NSUSerDefaults
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(printCost6, forKey: "printCost6")

// loading your Double data from NSUSerDefaults
let myLoadedDouble = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("printCost6")

println(myLoadedDouble)   // 2.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked. I do have a rather simple question that I am stuck on. I am using @iboutlet weak var qty = UITextField! or something to that matter (dont have the code in front of me) to get the input from the user from the text field. I was able to change this into an int but what I really need is a double. What is the easiest way to change that into a double?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary conditional operator:

```
let printCost6 = (userInputLoc1 <= 1 && userInputQty <= 23 ? 2.50 : 5 )
```